# split or multiple convex hull in python

Tags: python, numpy, 3d, 2d, convex-hull

I write script in python ,but I face a problem!
I am working in detecting cracks in pipeline by UT SCAN technique reading.
So, if I have crack I need to visualize it in 2D AND 3D.. I have numpy array has coordinates of x,y,z..
when it is always one crack, it is easy to find boundary or convex hull for one crack ,But if there is more, I need to visualize all of it in one panel and this will make problem because convex hull dealing with it as one object and will ignore distance between them and making boundary with all of them.

Any ideas for this problem? like how I can split each crack and dealing with them separately and find boundary convex hull and visualizing them.

Comment: Are we talking about scipy.spatial.ConvexHull or did you write a convex hull finder algorithm yourself?

Comment: yes, I  use  scipy.spatial.ConvexHull

Comment: As a very general comment (don't know if it helps), you would have to cluster your points first, label each cluster differently and then apply complex hull algorithm on each cluster. I've no idea how to do that with scipy, however.

Comment: Do you anything about DBSCAN?

Comment: No, sorry, can't help you there.